# probability functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The total time, measured in units of $100$ hours, that a teenager runs her hair dryer over a period of one year is a continuous random variable $X$ that has the density function 
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x, &0\lt x\lt 1,\\
2-x,& 1\le x\lt 2,\\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

Use Theorem 4.6 to evaluate the mean of the random variable $Y = 60X^2 + 39X$, where $Y$ is equal to the number of kilowatt hours expended annually.

[image]

Comment: Hi guys, I don't know this kind of questions, could you please tell me steps of this kind of question. I need to do as soon as possible. THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP

Comment: nobody knows what Theorem 4.6 is. And use mathjax to enter your question.

Comment: i JUST ADD tHEOREM 4.6

Comment: Loading the image is way too slow for me.  Could you just type in Theorem 4.6 instead of using an image?  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you mean $y= 60x^2+ 39x$ and the probability distribution of x is given by P(x)= x if $0< x\le 1$ and 2- x if 1< x< 2. As a quick check, the "total probability" should be $\int_0^2 P(x)dx$$= \int_0^1 x dx+ \int_1^2 (2- x) dx$$= \left[(1/2)x^2\right]_0^1+ \left[2x- (1/2)x^2\right]_1^2= 1/2+ (4- 2)- (2- 1/2)= 1$.

The mean of y is, of course, $\int_0^2 y(x)P(x)dx= \int_0^1 (60x^2+ 39x)x dx+ \int_1^2 (60x^2+ 39x)(2- x)dx=$$ \int_0^1 (60x^3+ 39x^2) dx+ \int_1^2 (-60x^3+ 18x^2+ 78x) dx$.  Can you do those integrals?

Comment: YES tHANK YOU SO MUCH!